# make a select distinct sorting the results according to another column

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this table:

```
| DAY | TRIMESTER |
```

Day is an integer value, always increasing (it counts the seconds passing from day 0). TRIMESTER contains a String value ('FIRST','SECOND','THIRD',etc). I need to get the list of trimesters in the right order.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIMESTER FROM table
```

returns:

```
| TRIMESTER |
|   FIRST   |
|   THIRD   |
|   SECOND  |
```

I have assessed that this would solve my problem:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT TRIMESTER, SUM(DAY) FROM table GROUP BY TRIMESTER ORDER BY SUM(DAY)
```

Is there a nicer solution which would output what I need and that would require less computing done by the database? The database is Oracle 11g and the tables are supposed to become very big.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
| DAY | TRIMESTER |
|  0  |  FIRST    |
|  10 |  FIRST    |
|  12 |  FIRST    |
|  20 |  FIRST    |
|  30 |  SECOND   |
|  35 |  SECOND   |
|  46 |  THIRD    |
```

I need to get in order: 'FIRST','SECOND' and 'THIRD'. Anyway I have no control over the keys in the TRIMESTER column. They are strings and might just be *any* string, I can't order them by name. I only know that they cover a "range" of DAY values. E.g. if I had values of "DAY" between 31 and 34 in the example, they'd all have a "SECOND" value in the trimester column.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY`:

```
select TRIMESTER 
from MyTable 
group by trimester 
order by max(DAY)
```

[SQL Fiddle Example #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ed2e/7)

Using `RANK` and `PARTITION`:

```
SELECT TRIMESTER
FROM (
  SELECT TRIMESTER,
  RANK() OVER (partition by TRIMESTER ORDER BY DAY DESC) DAYRANK
  FROM MyTable)
WHERE DAYRANK = 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle Example #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ed2e/6)

Comment: unluckily this is not a suitable solution. In the future the database will contain keys in the TRIMESTER column such as 'FIRST2010','SECOND2010','FIRST2011' and that would obviously not work. I need to keep them strictly in the order they appear following the order of DAY. I noticed now I forgot a ORDER BY SUM(DAY) in my solution... with that, my solution is supposed to always work as DAY is an always increasing positive integer. But I'm wary of the possible load on the server.

Comment: Ideally you woudl normalize the db and have the year separate from the trimester. If this is not possible, change the values to `2010FIRST`, `2011FIRST`, etc., and they will still sort correctly. If you get into having to do string operations on TRIMESTER to extract separate values in order to sort, you will have a significant performance hit.

Comment: I'd really like it to be so. The problem is that actually that table has more fields than those (all of them needing to be ordered in that way, for instance at the moment I have SEASON and YEAR too) but I can't rely on any of them or on their content besides a 'base' column that gets read from a xml file, and that base column is my 'DAY' column in this case. I just came out with this other 'safe' solution:
    SELECT DISTINCT TRIMESTER, MIN(DAY) FROM table GROUP BY TRIMESTER ORDER BY MIN(DAY)
Hopefully that generates much less overhead than a possibly huge sum operation.

Comment: @MarcoSacchetto I can't follow you any more, Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Sorry RedFilter. Look at the table in my first post. Assume that 'DAY' is a positive, always increasing integer value and is the primary key. TRIMESTER keys are strings but I have no control about what will be put inside it. I only know that a  certain range of DAY keys matches a single TRIMESTER key, eg: for DAY keys between 0 and 1000 TRIMESTER is "FIRST", for DAY between 1001 and 2000 TRIMESTER is "SECOND"... and so on. I need to retrieve the TRIMESTER values in order according to the values stored in DAY: the TRIMESTER keys with a lower DAY come first. Both my solutions do that.

Comment: This should do it: `select trimester from mytable group by trimester order by max(Day)`. [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1ed2e/2)

Comment: both working, thanks. The first one is faster when executing so I'll use it, anyway the 2nd possibility was an interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT   TRIMESTER
FROM     MY_TABLE
GROUP BY TRIMESTER
ORDER BY MIN (DAY);
```

Comment: mmm great, still not changing much from the second solution i posted among the follow-up to RedFilter's answer. Anyway I guess there's no quicker way to do it.